# Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 appears to be loaded but still no internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers

[Picture of my screen after issuing some relevant commands](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10iuw0qWgaN_z14cEYUCG6VyoSyyyqQ_s)

(Sorry, is there a way to copy past text from a Linux machine to a Windows machine when one of them has to internet connectivity? Mods: If this is inappropriate let me know; apologies in advance.)

I got the 3165 driver from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html , and followed instructions at some of the related user posts on askubuntu.com, including copying the originals to firmware and cp renaming them to the versions recommended.

---

Update:
I rebooted, and now `sudo ifconfig wlp10s0 up` works (the wireless drivers lists upon `ifconfig`), but still not wireless to reach `archives.ubuntu.com`.

[Updated view of monitor output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10nchyjTKTuZt0AbjbBlkAfJmLBTMmGLz)

---

Update: I am looking at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593735/unblocking-a-wireless-network-adapter-without-the-use-of-rfkill) and it seems I may just need another wireless adapter, if rfkill isn't allowing the one in the mobo to be unblocked.

---

Update: I coughed up the dough and bought [the antenna wifi card from ThinkPenguin](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/penguin-wireless-n-usb-adapter-w-external-antenna-gnu-linux-tpe-n150usbl) to avoid the hassle. I'm proud of this purchase, though, as it seems to support an excellent organization.

I will update you once it arrives and I install it.

---

Update:

The Penguin WiFi card marketed as "it just works" DOES NOT WORK. I plug it into the server and I still have no WiFi. It's a hastle to return it so I'm going to keep it... just in case. I've tried just about everything (not really, but a lot of struggle) on this thing and now the hardware is faulting... but nothing has exploded... yet. I'm glad it's built well and has a solid OS to serve, but it would be neat to speed up the construction process. I have big plans.

Comment: Can you run `sudo rfkill list` in the terminal and post the result please. Thanks.

Comment: The `rfkill` command is not found, and I can't `apt-get` it. -_-